# Overriding Django ModelForm save method and deleting old values(files)

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have a model and a ModelForm from the model mentioned. The model has an image field among others. As I update an instance of the model using the ModelForm, if the image field has been updated, I want the old file to be deleted. So I override the save method on the ModelForm. However, I am getting an unexpected outcome.

When the image field is updated, if there **NO** was a file previously, the new one is saved perfectly. But when there **WAS** a file previously, it does get stored in the file system but it's not saved to the instance. Thus the image field becomes empty.

The model example

```py
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    cover_image = model.ImageField()
```

The Form

```py
from django.core.files.uploadedfile import InMemoryUploadedFile
from django.db.models.fields.files import ImageFieldFile, FileField


class ArticleModelForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = '__all__'

    def save(self, commit=True):
        object = super().save(commit)

        # Clean out the old files
        for key in self.changed_data:
            new_value = self.cleaned_data.get(key)

            if new_value and isinstance(new_value, InMemoryUploadedFile):
                old_value = self.initial.get(key)

                if old_value and (isinstance(old_value, FileField) or isinstance(old_value, ImageFieldFile)):
                    old_value.delete()

        return object
```

On the override save method what I did is loop through all changed data and do the following;

1. Get the new value for the field.
2. If the new value is an instance of `InMemoryUploadedFile`, retrieve
   it's previous value from `self.initial` which is the old value.
3. If the old value is an instance of `FileField` or `ImageFieldFile`,
   it gets **DELETED**.

The new value somehow gets lost in this process.

Can someone explain the behavior of the file not being saved to the instance.

Django version 2.1.5
Commit is always `True`

Comment: `super().save(commit)` will already assign the new value. You thus should implement the logic *before* you can `super().save(commit)`.

Comment: I have tried `super().save(commit)` both before and after the logic but I get same behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this, it works just fine in terms of auto deleting old files and pictures.
https://pypi.org/project/django-cleanup/

Comment: I've seen the project and I am considering it. My original question was the reason for this behavior?